# FastAPI - GCP - Docker. SSLEOFError. UNEXPECTED_EOF_WHILE_READING

Tags: python, ssl, google-cloud-platform, fastapi

So, i have a microservice infrastructure mounted on GCP, its made with Python, FastAPI, and its dockerized. I have communication between those APIs (about 7 apis) via HTTP requests. 3 weeks ago one error started appearing without me touching any of the code.

This is a communication between Shipping API -> E-CommerceCommunication API.

This is the error that started happening.

```
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='anyurl', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /anyEndpoint (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, '[SSL: UNEXPECTED_EOF_WHILE_READING] EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1002)')))
```

Weird thing is, this is happening on the Shipping API, after it generates guides (which is an HTTP request)

So, the workflow is the next: Generate Guides (HTTP Request) -> Generate PDFs for the guides (HTTP Request) -> Send shipping info to E-Commerce (HTTP Request. This is where it fails).

this is my dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.11-slim-bookworm

COPY . . 

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 4 --worker-class uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker --timeout 3600 Main:app
```

this is my requirements file.

```
-i https://pypi.org/simple
anyio==3.7.0 ; python_version >= '3.7'
cachetools==5.3.1 ; python_version >= '3.7'
certifi==2023.5.7 ; python_version >= '3.6'
charset-normalizer==3.1.0 ; python_full_version >= '3.7.0'
click==8.1.3 ; python_version >= '3.7'
colorama==0.4.6 ; platform_system == 'Windows'
fastapi==0.99.1
fuzzywuzzy==0.18.0
google-api-core==2.11.1 ; python_version >= '3.7'
google-auth==2.21.0 ; python_version >= '3.6'
google-cloud-core==2.3.2 ; python_version >= '3.7'
google-cloud-storage==2.10.0
google-crc32c==1.5.0 ; python_version >= '3.7'
google-resumable-media==2.5.0 ; python_version >= '3.7'
googleapis-common-protos==1.59.1 ; python_version >= '3.7'
greenlet==2.0.2 ; platform_machine == 'aarch64' or (platform_machine == 'ppc64le' or (platform_machine == 'x86_64' or (platform_machine == 'amd64' or (platform_machine == 'AMD64' or (platform_machine == 'win32' or platform_machine == 'WIN32')))))
gunicorn==20.1.0
h11==0.14.0 ; python_version >= '3.7'
idna==3.4 ; python_version >= '3.5'
levenshtein==0.21.1
numpy==1.25.0 ; python_version >= '3.10'
pandas==2.0.3
protobuf==4.23.3 ; python_version >= '3.7'
pyasn1==0.5.0 ; python_version >= '2.7' and python_version not in '3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5'
pyasn1-modules==0.3.0 ; python_version >= '2.7' and python_version not in '3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5'
pydantic==1.10.10 ; python_version >= '3.7'
pymysql==1.1.0
pypdf==3.12.0
python-dateutil==2.8.2 ; python_version >= '2.7' and python_version not in '3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3'
python-dotenv==1.0.0
python-multipart==0.0.6
pytz==2023.3
rapidfuzz==3.1.1 ; python_version >= '3.7'
requests==2.31.0 ; python_version >= '3.7'
rsa==4.9 ; python_version >= '3.6' and python_version < '4'
setuptools==68.0.0 ; python_version >= '3.7'
six==1.16.0 ; python_version >= '2.7' and python_version not in '3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3'
sniffio==1.3.0 ; python_version >= '3.7'
sqlalchemy==2.0.17
starlette==0.27.0 ; python_version >= '3.7'
suds==1.1.2
typing-extensions==4.7.1 ; python_version >= '3.7'
tzdata==2023.3 ; python_version >= '2'
urllib3==1.26.16 ; python_version >= '2.7' and python_version not in '3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5'
uvicorn==0.22.0
```

This is the requests to from Shipping API -> E-CommerceComm-API

```py
from Models.PydanticSchemes.GuidesScheme import DbGuides
import requests

class ECommerceCommunicationsAPI():

    @staticmethod
    def UpdateOrders(Orders: list[DbGuides]):


        URL = "https://myurl.com/updateOrders"

        payload = []

        for order in Orders:

            tracking_urls = {
            "Domina" : f"https://oriontracking.infokairos.com.co/envios/{order.GuideNumber}/tracking/cliente",
            "E-Box" : f"https://enviexpresslogistica.com/tracking/result/?NoGuia={order.GuideNumber}",
            "Coordinadora" : f"https://www.coordinadora.com/portafolio-de-servicios/servicios-en-linea/rastrear-guias/?guia={order.GuideNumber}"
            }

            orderJson = {
                "OrderNumber" : order.OrderNumber,
                "GuideNumber" : order.GuideNumber,
                "Company" :  order.Company,
                "Tracking_URL" : tracking_urls[order.Company]
            }

            payload.append(orderJson)
        
        response = requests.post(URL, json = payload, verify = False) # Remove verif
```

I had my docker python image to Python:3 but changed it to the actual one.
Removed all the requirements and reinstalled
Uninstalled pyopenssl
Try pushing the container to a new Google instance.

Nothing above worked.

Comment: Any luck on solving this issue? I'm running into the same thing with a near identical setup. Will keep you posted if I figure something out

Comment: Same here, any updates?

Comment: Not really. I change Requests lib for HTTPX and the error code changed, but kept happening. Please, if anyone has any info just post it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was impacted by this same error with a near identical setup and switching from `requests` to `httpx` worked for me. I'm still not 100% sure why this worked but changing `requests.post` to `httpx.post` might resolve the error.

Comment: Hey, at least the error code changed. Now im getting this: ('[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1006)',)

Answer (score 1):

The issue exists inside the Docker image
**FROM python:3.11-slim-bookworm**

The issue was the OpenSSL version on this image. To solve this you have to change manually the OpenSSL version of your image or use this image that uses OpenSSL 1.1.1
**FROM python:3.9-slim-buster**

Comment: Oh wow good find. Going to try this now

Answer (score 0):

The answer for @starball works for me. I have added this to my dockerfile and it works: RUN apk update && apk upgrade openssl